# How to get id of an element when using Capybara for test (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing

I am using Capybara to write test in my application, but now i have a situation in which i need to read id of an element within capybara like

`myid = page.find("#parentNode").first(".childClass").id`

Consider i have the below HTML structure

```
<div id="parentNode">
 <div id="childNode1" class="childClass">1</div>
 <div id="childNode2" class="childClass">2</div>
</div>
```

**Please Note :** I am not trying to read the content of the child node, but the id. The above shown is for example.

**Expected Output :** childNode1 (id of first element with class childClass

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are almost near the answer. The only change is instead of calling id as method, you have to call it as attribute as follows

```
page.find("#parentNode").first(".childClass")[:id]
```

Comment: Good answer. Just want to add that if you want to store the id in a variable you should do something like this `myid = "#" + page.find("#parentNode").first(".childClass")[:id]`

Answer (score 1):

I would use some xpath instead of css in this case.
Note I am not that skilled in xpathing so I use css first to find parentNode.

```
find(#parentNode).find(:xpath, div[1]).id
```

Try that and see if it works.

optionally you can use css in the second find as well and use the class as criteria since it finds the first element anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer..!!

We can use `page.evaluate_script` to achieve this. I used the below code

`page.evaluate_script('$("#parentNode .childNode").first().attr("id")')`

Hope this will help some one :)